# Nil Coalescing Operator with mixed types

Tags: swift, null, option-type, default-value, null-coalescing-operator

Is there any good concise swifty way to take an optional of a non-String type and get a String value that is either the String interpretation of that value if it is .some() or some default value if it is .none() besides the following:

```
let statusCode = (resp as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode
let statusCodeString: String
if let statusCode = statusCode {
    statusCodeString = "\(statusCode)"
} else {
    statusCodeString = "None"
}
```

It just seems awfully verbose for a relatively simple thing, and it feels like I'm missing something obvious.

Just using the nil-coalescing operator doesn't work because you have to provide a default value of the same type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write some thing like this:

```
let statusCodeString = statusCode?.description ?? "None"
```

Or if you want to work with some types which does not have the property `description`:

```
let statusCodeString = statusCode.map{String(describing: $0)} ?? "None"
```

Comment: That does it, particularly the general use case. Thanks!

Comment: `.map{String(describing: $0)}` be more simply written as `.map(String.init(describing:))`

Comment: @Alexander, thanks. But it's my preference and mine is two character less than yours.

Comment: @OOPer It adds an unnecessary level of closureness

Comment: @Alexander, you can expect a good optimization for non-escaping closures, that's why it's become default.